# T1 Spaces, Continuity and Preservation of Adherence

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be $T1$ topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be an adherence preserving function, in other words:

$\forall A,B \subseteq X, (A\cap\overline{B}) \cup(\overline{A}\cap B)\neq\emptyset$ implies $(f(A)\cap\overline{f(B)}) \cup(\overline{f(A)}\cap f(B))\neq\emptyset$

I proved $f$ is continuous under these assumptions but I didn’t use the fact $X$ is $T1$.

Was I wrong or really this assumption is not needed?

This is my proof:

Let $C\subseteq Y$ be a closed set and suppose $f^{-1}(C)\subseteq X$ is not closed. This means it exists $x\in X$ such that $x\in\overline{f^{-1}(C)}$ and $x\notin f^{-1}(C)$.
$\{x\}\cap\overline{f^{-1}(C)}\neq\emptyset$ and therefore $\{x\}$ and $f^{-1}(C)$ are adherent.
Now, $f$ preserves adherence by hypothesis, in other words:
$(f(\{x\})\cap\overline{f(f^{-1}(C))})\cup(\overline{f(\{x\})}\cap f(f^{-1}(C)))=(\{f(x)\}\cap\overline{f(f^{-1}(C))})\cup(\overline{\{f(x)\}}\cap f(f^{-1}(C)))\neq\emptyset$
Let’s examine the intersections:

1. $f(f^{-1}(C))\subseteq C$, therefore $\overline{f(f^{-1}(C))}\subseteq\overline{C}=C$ and $f(x)\notin C$ so $(\{f(x)\}\cap\overline{f(f^{-1}(C))})=\emptyset$
2. $Y$ is $T1$, therefore $\{f(x)\}$ is closed, in other words, $\{f(x)\}=\overline{\{f(x)\}}$ and $(\overline{\{f(x)\}}\cap f(f^{-1}(C)))= (\{f(x)\}\cap f(f^{-1}(C)))=\emptyset$

   This provides the contradiction.

Comment: Well, post your proof attempt and we can see, maybe..

Comment: I’ve just added my proof…

Comment: You indeed only use that $Y$ is $T_1$. It does not matter what $\overline{\{x\}}$ is AFAICS.

Comment: Thanks for answering Henno, I was having doubts because this is indeed an exercise taken from my textbook, it seemed so strange to me an hypothesis was not being used…

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In Part 2, "$Y$ is $T_1$, therefore $\{x\}$ is closed." But $x\in X$, not $x\in Y$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet he clearly uses and means that $\{f(x)\}$ is closed. The first part is just recapping that $T_1$ iff singletons are closed , as I read it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah sure, that was a typo.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no use of X being T1.